# Write minimum 10 elements from the set $A$

Tags: recursion

Write minimum 10 elements from the set $A$ defined recursively as follow

$$\begin{cases} {1\in A, 2\in A, 3\in A}\\ {x+6\in A, x\in A}\end{cases}$$

Comment: You mean that $A$ is the smallest set with $1,2,3\in A$ and with $x+6\in A$ whenever $x\in A$? To begin with, try to find a few more elements that must belong to $A$. Then argue why no other small elements are $\in A$.

Comment: This is unclear, but if it says what I think it says, for any element in the set, $x+6$ in the set.

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen: please tell me how it is solved in detail so i can then make similar examples myself